# Why set a shared lock when duplicate-key error occurs during insert

Tags: mysql, innodb

As [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB, INSERT section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) said,

> INSERT sets an exclusive lock on the inserted row.
> Prior to inserting the row, a type of gap lock called an insert intention gap lock is set.

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set.

I wonder why set a shared lock, as the subsequent doc said, this might lead to a deadlock. Why not simply request an exclusive lock?

> This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another session already has an exclusive lock.

---

The below example copied from the MySQL document which demonstrate how to trigger the deadlock.

> CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, PRIMARY KEY (i)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Now suppose that three sessions perform the following operations in order:

Session 1:

> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
> ```

Session 2:

> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
> ```

Session 3:

> ```
> START TRANSACTION;
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
> ```

Session 1:

> ```
> ROLLBACK;
> ```

Comment: What is the goal here?  Learning how the Engine works?  Trying to avoid such a lock?  Something else?  Meanwhile, I suggest the developers did that for some reason -- perhaps some edge case that is not obvious.

Comment: Just the reason why set the shared lock on index record? We encountered the deadlock as above shown. @RickJames