# Why MySQL set a shared lock when insert encounter a duplicate-key error

Tags: mysql

here is my confusion. When I use mysql unique index record as a distribute lock, encounter a deadlock situation.

My table(id, seq)has a unique index on column seq, session1 delete one record(seq=10), session2 and session3 wait to insert record with same seq.

I have read MySQL doc about innodb locks: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html, found that MySQL set a shared lock when insert encounter a duplicate-key error, when session1 finished, session2&3 got the shared lock and request an exclusive lock, so they deadlocked.

My Question is, why MySQL set that shared lock? Could it better by setting a exclusive lock directly?

Comment: Similar question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031665/why-set-a-shared-lock-when-duplicate-key-error-occurs-during-insert

Comment: Similar question I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270714/why-mysql-innodb-set-an-s-or-x-next-key-lock-on-the-duplicate-index-record-when

Comment: The problem is with this question is that you are asking us to second guess mysql developer's thought process and engage in an academic discussion. It is academic, since it does not matter if we agree here that an exclusive lock at the beginning would be better, mysql will still place a shared lock and there is very little you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help~Haha, maybe my question is not so concrete. I will follow the issue and guess developer's thought after learning more about mysql~